# javascript self and arguments usage

Tags: javascript, node.js

im new to javascript. i have a simple question here.

i see below code snipet:

```
var self = this;
.....
self.push = function () {
    var args = [].concat.apply([], arguments);
    args.forEach(self.write);
    return self;
};

self.write is another function.
```

q1: why set self = this.

q2: why we can not write the push function as simple as arguments.forEach(self.write);

Answer (score 3):

> q1: why set self = this.

That is used when an inner function wants to keep a reference to an outer function's `this` in a closure. The value of `this` is set by how a function is called, so the inner function has its own `this` that "shaddows" the outer function's `this`.

> q2: why we can not write the push function as simple as arguments.forEach(self.write);

Becaue the [*arguments* object](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) is not an array so doesn't have a `forEach` method. The line:

```
var args = [].concat.apply([], arguments);
```

creates an array with members from the *arguments* object. It could also do:

```
[].forEach.call(arguments, ...)
```

or (preferred by many):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(arguments, ...);
```

#### Edit

A point raised by Jack is that it seems as if `this` in the function is `self` anyway. But `this` is set by the call, not by how the function is assigned or created (ignoring [ES5 bind](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5)) so you can't tell what the function's `this` will be until you see the call. You haven't posted that so we don't know. e.g.

```
self.push = function () {
    ...
}
```

Here, if the function is called as `self.push()` then its `this` is set to `self` anyway. However, if its `this` is set to something else, e.g.

```
var pushAlias = self.push;
...
pushAlias();
```

Here `self.push` is called without its `this` being set, so it will default to the global/window object (or undefined in strict mode). Using `self` within the function means that that doens't matter, the function still has a reference to the outer `this` at the time it was assigned to the `push` method.

Comment: The `self` doesn't really seem to do anything here though, referencing `this` inside the `.push()` method would be correct as well.

Answer (score 0):

Q1 In Javascript, "this" can be different things at different times, by making self "this" it means that the "this" at the time of that assignment will always be the this used.

Q2 arguments looks a little like an array but it's not, so first it creates an array so array functions can be called on it.